# Unable to convert array buffer to string?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, protocol-buffers

I've been trying to convert an array buffer to a human readable string, but when I try to decode the array buffer it returns foreign characters instead.

```
arrayBuffer = `[18, 32, 121, 49, 72, 220, 122, 210, 56, 86, 171, 17, 36, 81, 52, 151, 102, 70, 216, 254, 207, 175, 161, 253, 216, 30, 99, 35, 30, 121, 226, 96, 86, 94]` 
var readableString = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(arrayBuffer)
```

I try to decode the array by using `text-encoding` package and but it returns y1H�z�8V�$Q4�fF��ϯ���c#y�`V^. Is there any reason why it's unable to be decoded into a human readable string?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextDecoder` is probably looking at raw binary data of the numbers, and then converting that into a UTF-8 string. C/C++ has this behavior. If you want to turn it into a human readable string, you can use `Array.join` or similar to convert it into a string. Sample code:

```js
arrayBuffer = [18, 32, 121, 49, 72, 220, 122, 210, 56, 86, 171, 17, 36, 81, 52, 151, 102, 70, 216, 254, 207, 175, 161, 253, 216, 30, 99, 35, 30, 121, 226, 96, 86, 94];
var readableString = "[" + arrayBuffer.join(", ") + "]";
console.log(readableString)
```